# CSVHelper cannot convert empty float values to string

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have a csv file that contains integer, string, bool, and float types of data. The problem is, that some fields are empty. When I try to read the csv file with csvhelper, I get TypeConversion.TypeConverterException error. I checked the details, and looks like it's because it can't convert the empty float values to string. How can I handle it?

```
namespace Smh
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<E> EList = new List<E>();
            List<E2> EList2 = new List<E2>();

            string filePath = @"D:\Visual Studio\Projects\Example\boo.csv";

            using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
            using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
            {
                var example= new E();
                EList= csv.GetRecords<E>().ToList();
            }
.
.
.
```

A part of my "E" class:

```
.
.
 public float weight { get; set; }
.
.
```

and the error I get:
https://i.postimg.cc/dVPkYDCm/image.png

A short part of the csv file:

```
id | speed | type | weight
1     40     type1   5.4
2     43     type2
3     16     type3   5.2
```

Comment: What do you want the value to be? NaN, Infinity, 0.0? Proposal: make `weight` a string and implement the setter in a way that it does the float parsing.

Comment: I think 'NaN' would be the best solution. What do you mean by "implement the setter in a way that it does the float parsing"?

Comment: May we have an [mre], a simple Csv with 1 or 2 column and maximum five row. With the said the Class representing and the mapper information.

Comment: Edited the question with a minimal example. The point is, that "weight" has a field that doesn't contain anything. (Ofc it has more in the real file)

Comment: A misssing value is a `null`, which means `weight` should be a `float?`.

Comment: Did you try setting your float as a `Nullable<float>` with `float?`. I think CsvHelper supports this.

Comment: If you don't want `float?`, you can create a [custom type converter](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/type-conversion) or specify a [custom conversion function](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/inline-type-conversion) during mapping

Comment: @Gimly could you show me how to set my ```public class float``` to Nullable float?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution with out using a `ClassMap` Custom mapper,
is to change the type to `float?`.

```
public class Test{
    public int id{get;set;}
    public int speed{get;set;}
    public string type{get;set;}
    public float? weight{get;set;}
}
```

Then If you need to change the default value you can add a Getter Setter that will return `Single.NaN`

Example:
[Live Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Zypdgu)

```
public static void Main()
{
    var result = new List<Test>();
    using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        //Csv Creation
        writer.WriteLine("id,speed,type,weight");
        writer.WriteLine("1,40,type1,5.4");
        writer.WriteLine("2,43,type2,");
        writer.WriteLine("3,16,type3,5.2");
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        
        
        csv.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = true;
        csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";
        
        result = csv.GetRecords<Test>().ToList();           
        
    }
    result.Dump();
}
```

Comment: It solved the problem, but ran into another. Looks like it can't handle the empty int values either. Is it possible to do the same like ```public int? something```?

Comment: Yes you can do the same.